# Linking opencv ".a" libraries with mingw and Qt 5.0

Tags: qt, opencv, static, mingw, .a

This one is tough ! Please don't mistake this for a newbie question ;) I have far too many miles in this OpenCV + MinGW static stuff for the simple mistakes....

Environment:
a. Qt 5.0.1 built with MinGW (the standard opensource download from qt-project) - so everything is built with the same MinGW environment.
b. Using CMake I setup minimal build (using the same g++/gcc as Qt) and turned OFF SHARED_LIBRARIES.
c. generated the cmake + mingw32-make + mingw32-make install works fine.

**up till here everything looks pretty smooth ...**

Now when I added:

```
win32-g++:INCLUDEPATH += D:/Dev/opencv/build/install/include
win32-g++:LIBS += -LD:/Dev/opencv/build/install/lib
win32-g++:LIBS += -static
win32-g++:LIBS += -llibopencv_core243d
win32-g++:LIBS += -llibopencv_imgproc243d
win32-g++:LIBS += -llibopencv_highgui243d
```

(and also without the "win32-g++" addition..)

I get `d:/dev/qt/qt5.0.1/tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibopencv_highgui243d`

```
...
...
```

**now.. I do have libopencv_highgui243d.a in the right directory, but the ld.exe linker is ignoring anything else than a lib ! which supposed to be a MS library (which I wanted to avoid in the first place!!!) - I even tried to rename the .a files to .lib which caused the linker to regard the files, but show many "unreferenced" errors...**

So who's to blame? the linker? CMake? mingw? Qt? ....

I tried many command line / flag options but without success ..

Comment: Hello mister expert, have you tried without the initial *lib*? Example: `LIBS += -lopencv_core243d`

Comment: I've had success in the past doing this stuff passing the full path to the file and full filename to `LIBS` (including the extension of the file. Example: `LIBS += D:/blah/blah/libopencv_highgui243d.a`

Comment: Hey Karlphillip.. that is most odd but you are true! it is very much odd because the filename is indeed libopencv_core243d.a (with the lib) so who on earth thought about cutting the start of the filename???? !!! WHAT A STUPID COMMANDLINE / CONVENTION ... ~~~~ That makes me angry! but thanks X100000 !

Comment: " I have far too many miles in this OpenCV + MinGW static stuff for the simple mistakes...." - My first thought: I bet the answer will be simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be referring to the libraries as:

```
LIBS += -lopencv_core243d
LIBS += -lopencv_imgproc243d
LIBS += -lopencv_highgui243d
```

Since `-l` already inserts *lib* at the beginning of the name.